# elastic query on how to search a particular field weather it is contained in some inner object or outer

Tags: elasticsearch

Example :

```
{
  "name": "nav"
}
```

or

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "nav"
  }
}
```

how to write a generic query to search for "name=nav" irrespective of the key occurring anywhere(outer or inner)

Comment: is data of type nested or object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try multi match using regex

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "nav",
      "fields": [ "*name" ] 
    }
  }
}
```